# Disable a link by adding a class and setting href with laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to disable a link by adding a class and setting its href.

I came up with this but I am not happy with it.

```
    <a class="linkclass {!! $disabled ? 'disabled' : '" href="/page' !!}">Link</a>
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this a good practice? Do you recommend setting href by its condition of being disabled?
2. Which is the way you would suggest to do that?

Comment: why not just do `href={{$link or '#'}}`?

Comment: What about the class? I want to set the class to disabled if the href is #.

Comment: I want to avoid the duplicity: if the link is active has href and no 'disabled' class, if it is disabled just the opposite. Taking this into account, is there any single condition solution?

Answer (score 1):

if `$disabled` is a bool

```
@if($disabled)
    <a class="linkclass disabled">Link</a> // or optional <a class="linkclass disabled" href="#">Link</a>
@else
    <a class="linkclass" href="/link">Link</a>
@endif
```

but maybe it's better to have `$disabled` also contain the class string value `"disabled"` or empty.

```
<a class="linkclass {{$disabled}}"href="@if(isset($disabled))#@else /link @endif"></a>
```

Comment: Ok @ThomasMoors, thanks for your answer, I assume maybe there is not a single condition solution. I suggest using ternary operator for the second solution `<a class="linkclass {{$disabled}}" href="{{isset($disabled) ? '#' : '/link'}}"></a>`

Comment: Why is this so bad in your opinion? This is at least escaped already, which is more secure. It also does not add a notable performance decrease at all, so what is the problem you have with this solution?

Comment: I don't think this is bad. Maybe it is a bad question! I was asking for a all-in-one solution like my first code.